# Uppy Dashboard - disableLocalFiles: true with Webcam enabled - hides the camera option on iOS while it still shows on desktop chrome

Tags: javascript, file-upload, safari, uppy

Link to runnable example
https://codepen.io/jakemcallister-the-reactor/pen/jOemvbV

Steps to reproduce
A basic example with with disableLocalFiles set to true.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.8.0/uppy.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need JavaScript enabled for this example to work.</noscript>
    <button id="uppyModalOpener">Open Modal</button>

    <script type="module">
      import {
        Uppy,
        Dashboard,
        Webcam,
      } from "https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.8.0/uppy.min.mjs";

      const uppy = new Uppy({ debug: true, autoProceed: false })
        .use(Dashboard, { trigger: "#uppyModalOpener", disableLocalFiles: true })
        .use(Webcam, { target: Dashboard })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Expected behavior**

1. Disable the drag files onto the modal to upload
2. Remove the "my device" button
3. Leave only the camera option

**Actual behavior**

On mac chrome it works as expected:

[image]

However on iOS safari it shows just an empty modal

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why it's not showing the camera on iOS Safari or Android chrome?

Docs: https://uppy.io/docs/quick-start/